# Error when using pst-poker: rungs not found? (texlive)

Tags: errors, packages, texlive, pstricks

After installing the 2022 edition of texlive I get the following error when trying to use the pst-poker package:

> C:\texlive\2022\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:858: no appropriate script or
> program found: rungs

Looking in the folder "rungs.exe" is present, so I'm not sure why it can't utilize it (something wrong with runscript?). This did not occur in the prior version I have installed nor does it occur if one tries this in Overleaf.

Here is a simple example to demonstrate what I mean:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-poker}

\begin{document}
\As 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Run your example with `lualatex` instead of `latex` or `xelatex`